# Can one conditionally import a module in NodeJS/React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working with a React/NodeJS project where I want to be able to *conditionally* import a Node module if and only if a parameter is *not* passed to my component via a prop

```
const WysiwygField = ({ onChange, autoFocus, field, errors, value: serverValue }) => {
   if (!field.config.apiKey) import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
....
}
```

I suspect because of the way Node modules work that this isn't possible.  I've done some googling but am getting confused between the concept of conditional importing -- which https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports seems to say one can't do in NodeJS and dynamic importing, for which there seems to be Babel support: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import.

Is this a dead-end, or is there any way to do what I want to do?  (The reason for this is because of the way that `tinymce-react` works: if the TinyMCE package hasn't been imported, then it goes to the CDN, where the passed `apiKey` is of use. The reason why I don't just code it that way to begin with, that is, just make sure it never loads the local library, is because I'm working within a larger framework where I don't have the liberty to preclude that option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Dynamic Imports` to achieve this. 
Like:

```
const A = condition && import('./a.js')
```

Although to use dynamic imports you will have to use `babel`.

Comment: out of curiosity, does this assign the value of 'import' to 'const A'? it looks like it will just import the module without assigning it to a variable

Comment: this looks like it will work according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do conditional imports with the require syntax - something like:

```
let someImport;
if (condition) someImport = require('module');
```

Comment: Does it need to be at the top of the module, that is, external to everything, or can it be anywhere?

Comment: anywhere i think - sorry, didnt see this